# 18.04 L2TP VPN Config - what am I missing?

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, vpn, ipsec

I've been trying to get an Ubuntu laptop to connect to our L2TP VPN server, I have tried using both 18.04 and 19.04, following a couple of tutorials which basically amounted to installing `network-manager-l2tp` and `network-manager-l2tp-gnome`. I've gotten to this point:

```
May 17 12:34:14 lap-linux-001 NetworkManager[583]: <info>  [1558110854.8704] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="2dba1ee5-c86e-46e9-b0e4-5ce89738d380" name="ADS" pid=1509 uid=1000 result="success"
May 17 12:34:14 lap-linux-001 NetworkManager[583]: <info>  [1558110854.8758] vpn-connection[0x5603ef4be7a0,2dba1ee5-c86e-46e9-b0e4-5ce89738d380,"ADS",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 8635
May 17 12:34:14 lap-linux-001 NetworkManager[583]: <info>  [1558110854.8878] vpn-connection[0x5603ef4be7a0,2dba1ee5-c86e-46e9-b0e4-5ce89738d380,"ADS",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
May 17 12:34:18 lap-linux-001 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
May 17 12:34:19 lap-linux-001 NetworkManager[583]: <info>  [1558110859.3039] settings-connection[0x5603ef3ae480,2dba1ee5-c86e-46e9-b0e4-5ce89738d380]: write: successfully updated (keyfile: update /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ADS.nmconnection (2dba1ee5-c86e-46e9-b0e4-5ce89738d380,"ADS")), connection was modified in the process
May 17 12:34:19 lap-linux-001 NetworkManager[583]: <info>  [1558110859.3085] vpn-connection[0x5603ef4be7a0,2dba1ee5-c86e-46e9-b0e4-5ce89738d380,"ADS",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
May 17 12:34:19 lap-linux-001 nm-l2tp-service[8635]: Check port 1701
May 17 12:34:19 lap-linux-001 nm-l2tp-service[8635]: Can't bind to port 1701
May 17 12:34:19 lap-linux-001 NetworkManager[583]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec failed: starter is not running
May 17 12:34:21 lap-linux-001 NetworkManager[583]: Starting strongSwan 5.7.1 IPsec [starter]...
May 17 12:34:21 lap-linux-001 NetworkManager[583]: Loading config setup
May 17 12:34:21 lap-linux-001 NetworkManager[583]: Loading conn '2dba1ee5-c86e-46e9-b0e4-5ce89738d380'
May 17 12:34:21 lap-linux-001 NetworkManager[583]: found netkey IPsec stack
May 17 12:34:21 lap-linux-001 charon: 00[DMN] Starting IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.7.1, Linux 5.0.0-13-generic, x86_64)
May 17 12:34:21 lap-linux-001 charon: 00[CFG] loading ca certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/cacerts'
May 17 12:34:21 lap-linux-001 charon: 00[CFG] loading aa certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/aacerts'
May 17 12:34:21 lap-linux-001 charon: 00[CFG] loading ocsp signer certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/ocspcerts'
May 17 12:34:21 lap-linux-001 charon: 00[CFG] loading attribute certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/acerts'
May 17 12:34:21 lap-linux-001 charon: 00[CFG] loading crls from '/etc/ipsec.d/crls'
May 17 12:34:21 lap-linux-001 charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
May 17 12:34:21 lap-linux-001 charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-2dba1ee5-c86e-46e9-b0e4-5ce89738d380.secrets'
May 17 12:34:21 lap-linux-001 charon: 00[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
May 17 12:34:21 lap-linux-001 charon: 00[LIB] loaded plugins: charon aesni aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md4 md5 mgf1 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac gcm attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark stroke updown eap-mschapv2 xauth-generic counters
May 17 12:34:21 lap-linux-001 charon: 00[LIB] dropped capabilities, running as uid 0, gid 0
May 17 12:34:21 lap-linux-001 charon: 00[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads
May 17 12:34:21 lap-linux-001 charon: 06[CFG] received stroke: add connection '2dba1ee5-c86e-46e9-b0e4-5ce89738d380'
May 17 12:34:21 lap-linux-001 charon: 06[CFG] algorithm 'ecp_384' not recognized
May 17 12:34:21 lap-linux-001 charon: 06[CFG] skipped invalid proposal string: aes256-sha1-ecp_384
May 17 12:34:22 lap-linux-001 charon: 08[CFG] rereading secrets
May 17 12:34:22 lap-linux-001 charon: 08[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
May 17 12:34:22 lap-linux-001 charon: 08[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-2dba1ee5-c86e-46e9-b0e4-5ce89738d380.secrets'
May 17 12:34:22 lap-linux-001 charon: 08[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
May 17 12:34:22 lap-linux-001 charon: 09[CFG] received stroke: initiate '2dba1ee5-c86e-46e9-b0e4-5ce89738d380'
May 17 12:34:22 lap-linux-001 charon: 09[CFG] no config named '2dba1ee5-c86e-46e9-b0e4-5ce89738d380'
May 17 12:34:22 lap-linux-001 NetworkManager[583]: no config named '2dba1ee5-c86e-46e9-b0e4-5ce89738d380'
May 17 12:34:22 lap-linux-001 NetworkManager[583]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
May 17 12:34:22 lap-linux-001 charon: 00[DMN] signal of type SIGINT received. Shutting down
May 17 12:34:22 lap-linux-001 nm-l2tp-service[8635]: g_dbus_method_invocation_take_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
May 17 12:34:22 lap-linux-001 NetworkManager[583]: <info>  [1558110862.8278] vpn-connection[0x5603ef4be7a0,2dba1ee5-c86e-46e9-b0e4-5ce89738d380,"ADS",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
May 17 12:34:22 lap-linux-001 NetworkManager[583]: <info>  [1558110862.8313] vpn-connection[0x5603ef4be7a0,2dba1ee5-c86e-46e9-b0e4-5ce89738d380,"ADS",0]: VPN service disappeared
May 17 12:34:22 lap-linux-001 NetworkManager[583]: <warn>  [1558110862.8326] vpn-connection[0x5603ef4be7a0,2dba1ee5-c86e-46e9-b0e4-5ce89738d380,"ADS",0]: VPN connection: failed to connect: 'Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying'
```

I've also been able to get the connection working in Fedora, so I am pretty sure I am using the right configuration options, but I am not even seeing an option to disable PFS on the Ubuntu side.

From what I am reading, it seems like it is looking for a configuration that doesn't exist? But I'm not sure where it wants me to put/create/add it. Maybe ipsec.conf? But the string doesn't look like any other examples I have seen.

I'm not too experienced with Linux, but this is my first time meddling with the VPN. Thanks for giving this a read, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you the steps I needed to get my ipsec vpn working (on 18.04).

```
sudo apt install strongswan
```

Then install libcharon-extra-plugins and libstrongswan-extra-plugins.  I did this with synaptic package manager.  I needed these for module eap-identity.
Create correct /etc/ipsec.conf, based on vpn settings.
Create or modify ipsec.secrets

Some extra steps I needed, but this may be vpn dependent:

- in /etc/strongswan.d/charon/constraints.conf, change 'load = yes' to 'load = no'
- change certificates

  ```
    sudo rmdir /etc/ipsec.d/cacerts  (maybe make a backup first)
    sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs /etc/ipsec.d/cacerts
  ```
- Personally, I need the next for dns operation during vpn

  ```
    sudo apt install resolvconf
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
    reboot
  ```

Finally :

```
    sudo ipsec restart
    sudo ipsec up <vpn-name>
```

Hope this helps you a bit further.